# Warning about package:flutter/material.dart on flutter

Tags: flutter

How do we remove this warning on VS code? It's all over my flutter project but can not get rid of it.

```
Flutter 3.10.0 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git 
Framework • revision 84a1e904f4 (6 weeks ago) • 2023-05-09 07:41:44 -0700
Engine • revision d44b5a94c9
Tools • Dart 3.0.0 • DevTools 2.23.1
```

[image: material]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flutter` is missing from your dependencies in the `pubspec.yaml`. Make sure it's in it like

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
```